# Python: алгоритм формирования всех вариантов чисел из набора цифр

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list

Есть набор цифр, например `[0, 1, 2, 2]`

Подскажите алгоритм (вообще голова отключилась :)), чтобы сформировать все возможные уникальные наборы чисел, сформированных из указанных цифр, использованных по 1 разу, при этом числа не могут содержать в начале 0 (кроме самого 0)

Т.е. нужно сделать

```
res = []
res.extend(itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 2]))
res.extend(itertools.permutations([10, 2, 2]))
res.extend(itertools.permutations([10, 22]))
res.extend(itertools.permutations([20, 1, 2]))
res.extend(itertools.permutations([20, 12]))
res.extend(itertools.permutations([20, 21]))
... и т.д.

res = list(set(res))
```

но полностью автоматически.

Comment: Не понимаю `20, 12, 2` в примере. Слишком много двоек.

Comment: Порядок в наборе важен? Нужны оба `10 22` и `22 10`?

Comment: "Голова отключилась" - не мудрено. Задача сложная.

Comment: да, порядок важен, как вариант думал сделать с переводом сначала в строку и затем нарезкой строки

Comment: Вы подбираете ответ в математическом ребусе?

Comment: на счет примера `20, 12, 2` - опечатался, просто забыл стереть последнюю 2, должно быть `20, 12`

Answer (score 3):

Рекурсивный перебор комбинаций чисел. `digits` - словарь, перечисляющий цифры. Для цифр 0, 1, 2, 2 словарь будет `{2: 2, 0: 1, 1: 1}`.

Генератор `numbers(digits)` перечисляет все числа, которые можно построить из словаря `digits`. При перечислении словарь меняется - цифры, составляющие число, из словаря удалены. Например, когда выдаётся число 20, в словаре останется одна двойка и одна единица: `{2: 1, 1: 1}`. Эта особенность пригодится дальше.

Генератор `combinations(digits, combination)` перечисляет комбинации чисел, которые можно составить из `digits`. Он использует `numbers(digits)` для перечисления первых чисел. Хвост комбинации строится рекурсивно. При построении числа `digits` худеет, из него удаляются использованные цифры. Когда он опустел, комбинация готова.

`combinations` не публикует комбинации через `yield`. Вместо этого текущая комбинация записывается во второй аргумент. В цикле её можно обработать, но если вы хотите сохранить комбинацию, скопируйте её до конца итерации. На следующей итерации новая комбинация будет записана в тот же список. Так сделано для скорости.

```
import collections


def add(c, k):
    c[k] += 1


def remove(c, k):
    if c[k] == 1:
        del c[k]
    else:
        c[k] -= 1


def numbers(digits):

    def search(prefix):
        yield prefix
        for k in tuple(digits.keys()):
            remove(digits, k)
            yield from search(10 * prefix + k)
            add(digits, k)

    for k in tuple(digits.keys()):
        remove(digits, k)
        if k == 0:
            yield 0
        else:
            yield from search(k)
        add(digits, k)


def combinations(digits, combination):

    def search():
        if digits:
            for n in numbers(digits):
                combination.append(n)
                yield from search()
                combination.pop()
        else:
            yield

    return search()


def main():
    digits = collections.Counter(map(int, input()))
    combination = []
    for _ in combinations(digits, combination):
        print(*combination)


main()
```

> ```
> $ echo 0122 | python combinations.py
> 0 1 2 2
> 0 1 22
> 0 12 2
> 0 122
> 0 2 2 1
> 0 2 21
> 0 2 1 2
> 0 2 12
> 0 22 1
> 0 221
> 0 21 2
> 0 212
> 1 2 2 0
> 1 2 20
> 1 2 0 2
> 1 22 0
> 1 220
> 1 20 2
> 1 202
> 1 0 2 2
> 1 0 22
> 12 2 0
> 12 20
> 12 0 2
> 122 0
> 1220
> 120 2
> 1202
> 10 2 2
> 10 22
> 102 2
> 1022
> 2 2 0 1
> 2 2 1 0
> 2 2 10
> 2 20 1
> 2 201
> 2 21 0
> 2 210
> 2 0 1 2
> 2 0 12
> 2 0 2 1
> 2 0 21
> 2 1 2 0
> 2 1 20
> 2 1 0 2
> 2 12 0
> 2 120
> 2 10 2
> 2 102
> 22 0 1
> 22 1 0
> 22 10
> 220 1
> 2201
> 221 0
> 2210
> 20 1 2
> 20 12
> 20 2 1
> 20 21
> 201 2
> 2012
> 202 1
> 2021
> 21 2 0
> 21 20
> 21 0 2
> 212 0
> 2120
> 210 2
> 2102
> ```

Comment: Оффтоп: Вы при разработке сразу в категориях yield/генераторов алгоритм продумываете?

Comment: @MBo, если функция возвращает список значений, рассматриваю возможность генератора.

Comment: Ну так-то логично, хотя и привычнее иметь реальный возвращаемый физический объект, например, списка, а не функциональную надежду на будущее  ;) У вас здесь вообще безретёрновое программирование вышло, вот и любопытно.

Comment: @MBo, 1. в комбинаторике весь список можно ждать годами, а первый результат доступен через миллисекунду. 2. `yield` - тот же `return`, только его можно много раз вызывать.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

s = ['0', '1', '2', '2']
res=[]
for r in range(1, len(s) + 1):
    for i in filter(lambda x: x[0] != '0', itertools.permutations(s,r)):
        res.append(''.join(i))
print(res)
res=list(set(res))
res.insert(0,0)
print(sorted(map(int,res)))
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 10, 12, 20, 21, 22, 102, 120, 122, 201, 202, 210, 212, 220, 221, 1022, 1202, 1220, 2012, 2021, 2102, 2120, 2201, 2210]
```

Comment: супер, но нужна список списков (как в примере), сливать их в один список не нужно, т.е. будет список содержащий список из 4 элементов, 3х, 2х и 1 элемента (в случае четырехзначного числа) и уже каждый из вариантов можно расширить за счёт перестановки чисел внутри каждого подсписка

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
from itertools import permutations

digits = [0, 1, 2, 2]
digits_as_chars = map(str, digits)

perms = permutations(digits_as_chars)

result = [int("".join(per)) for per in perms]
result = [i for i in result if i >= 10 ** (len(digits) - 1)]
result = set(result)
```

---

*Результат (в переменной `result`):*

> ```
> {1022, 1202, 1220, 2012, 2021, 2102, 2120, 2201, 2210}
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

Условие `i >= 10 ** (len(digits) - 1)` в последнем генераторе списка гарантирует, что число не будет начинаться с нуля т.к. например в случае 4-значного числа оно будет более или равно `1000`.

Comment: Вы решаете другую задачу.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, может быть, но в задаче было *«сформированных из указанных цифр, использованных по 1 разу»*, что я понял как **точно** по 1 разу. Как это поняли вы?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, но это касается только цифры **2**, которая в списке находится дважды. Т.е. каждый элемент списка находится точно один раз.

Comment: Ответом должен быть список списков: `[[0, 1, 2, 2], [0, 122], [12, 20], ..., [2210]]`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, может быть. Лучше всего бы было, когда бы откликнулся сам автор вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Решение получилось неочевидным, постараюсь объяснить логику работы на примерах. В общих чертах, сначала формируем все возможные комбинации из цифр исходного списка. В итоге получаем комбинации  цифр из исходного списка. Далее формируем список двухзначных, трехзначных и четырехзначных чисел (10, 22, 120, 221, 2210, 1022 и т.д.). Затем нужно сформировать комбинации полученных двух- и трехзначных с цифрами из исходного списка. Например, для числа 12 формируем комбинации для оставшихся цифр 0 и 2. Для числа 102 комбинации с 2. Для числа 12 можно также сформировать комбинации из 12 и 20, для этого уже обработанный список из 0 и 2 и число 12 сохраняем в очереди для повторной обработки, но уже для комбинации чисел 12 и 20. Алгоритм работает для разных комбинаций исходных данных, например, для списков [0,1,2,2,3] или [1,2,4,7,8,9] и т.п.

```
from itertools import permutations
from functools import reduce
from collections import deque, Counter
from typing import NamedTuple

input_list = [0, 1, 2, 2]  #Входные данные

# Класс данных для удобства загрузки-выгрузки данных в очередь
class ComboNums(NamedTuple):
    Nums_List: list[int]
    Input_List: list[int]

res = set()
# Предварительно обрабатываем каждое отдельное значение исходного списка
# В результирующий список сохраняем все комбинации из цифр исходного списка и удаляем дубли
res = set(permutations(input_list))

# Очередь потребуется для хранения списков, требующих обработки
query_buff: deque = deque()
# Перед запуском цикла обработки загружаем в очередь исходный список
query_buff.append(ComboNums(list(), input_list))

while query_buff:
    # Пока в очереди есть что обрабатывать выгружаем список для обработки
    cnum: ComboNums = query_buff.pop()
    # Формируем генератор, который из цифр списка составляет двухзначные, трехзначные и т.д. числа
    # Т.к. числа, состоящие из одной цифры, уже обработаны, начинаем с двухзначных чисел
    gen_digits = ( digit
        for perms in (
            set(permutations(cnum.Input_List, i)) for i in range(2,len(cnum.Input_List)+1)
        )
        for digit in perms if digit[0] != 0 # Исключаем числа начинающиеся с нуля
        )
    # Перебираем все полученные двухзначные, трехзначные и т.д. числа
    for digits_list in gen_digits:
        # Удаляем из списка цифры, из которых состоят двухзначных, трехзначных и т.д. числа.
        # Например, для числа 12 из списка удаляем цифры 1 и 2, оставив 0 и 2
        digits_count = Counter(cnum.Input_List)
        digits_count.subtract(digits_list)
        buff_list = list(digits_count.elements())
        # Из отобранных цифр (в нашем примере 1 и 2) формируем число 12
        num = reduce(lambda dig_prev, dig_next: 10 * dig_prev + dig_next, digits_list)
        # В результирующий список записываем все возможные комбинации числа 12 и оставшихся в списке цифр 0 и 2
        res.update(set(permutations(cnum.Nums_List + [num] + buff_list)))
        # Т.к. в списке остались цифры 0 и 2, из которых можно
        # сформировать число 20 и комбинации (12,20) и (20,12),
        # сохраняем список из чисел 0 и 2, а также полученное 
        # число 12 в очереди для дальнейшей обработки
        if len(buff_list) > 1:
            query_buff.append(ComboNums(cnum.Nums_List + [num], buff_list))
# Формируем список результатов и сортируем его для удобства отображения
list_res = list(res)
list_res.sort()
print(list_res)
```